# sns.histplot legend colors not matching the output

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I am creating a combo boxplot\histplot.

Everything runs and I get the output I am expecting except for one thing:
The line colors in the legend do not match the output.

Code:

```
def boxhist(dfx, x):
    variable = dfx[x].values
    np.array(variable).mean()
    np.median(variable)

    f, (ax_box, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (0.5, 2)})
    mean = np.array(variable).mean()
    median = np.median(variable)

    sns.boxplot(variable, ax=ax_box)
    ax_box.axvline(mean, color='orange', linestyle='--')
    ax_box.axvline(median, color='black', linestyle='-')

    sns.histplot(data=variable, ax=ax_hist, kde=True, binwidth=2, facecolor='green').lines[0].set_color('red')
    ax_hist.axvline(mean, color='orange', linestyle='--')
    ax_hist.axvline(median, color='black', linestyle='-')

    plt.title(x, fontsize=10, loc='right')
    plt.legend({'Mean': mean, 'Median': median})
    ax_box.set(xlabel='')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

The mean should be orange.
The median should be black.

1. Why is the legend showing the mean as red and the median as orange?
2. I want the legend colors to match the plot output.  mean\orange, median\black.

Comment: @JohanC, I did this, but it did not have any effect:  ax_hist.axvline(mean, color='orange', label='Mean', linestyle='--')
    ax_hist.axvline(median, color='black', label='Median', linestyle='-')

Comment: @JohanC.  Ahh...  I also had to remove {'Mean': mean, 'Median': median} from my call to plt.legend().  Now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a label in `ax_hist.axvline(mean, ...., label='Mean')` (and similar for the median). Then matplotlib should automatically add them to the legend (when called without parameters).

Here is some example code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def boxhist(dfx, x):
     variable = dfx[x].values
     variable.mean()
     np.median(variable)

     f, (ax_box, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (0.5, 2)})
     mean = variable.mean()
     median = np.median(variable)

     sns.boxplot(x=variable, ax=ax_box)
     ax_box.axvline(mean, color='orange', linestyle='--')
     ax_box.axvline(median, color='black', linestyle='-')

     sns.histplot(x=variable, ax=ax_hist, kde=True, binwidth=2, facecolor='green')
     ax_hist.lines[0].set_color('red')

     ax_hist.axvline(mean, color='orange', linestyle='--', label='Mean')
     ax_hist.axvline(median, color='black', linestyle='-', label='Median')

     ax_hist.set_title(x, fontsize=10, loc='right')
     ax_hist.legend()
     # ax_box.set(xlabel='') # has no effect on shared x-axis
     plt.tight_layout()
     plt.show()

dfx = pd.DataFrame({'bmi': np.random.normal(30.2, 5, 100)})
boxhist(dfx, 'bmi')
```

[image: sns.histplot with mean line]